# SQL Server - Get row based on a sum

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate 5 working days from a given date, based on the table below.

5 working days from Jan 9 is Jan 16 because the sum of the `working_days` column below between those dates is 5.

Here is SQL that I used.

```
WITH dates AS
(
    SELECT t_from.start_date, t_to.start_date end_date
    FROM #t t_from, #t t_to
    WHERE t_from.start_date < t_to.start_date 
),
sum_days AS 
(
    SELECT
        start_date, end_date,
        (SELECT SUM(t_sum.working_days) 
         FROM #t t_sum 
         WHERE t_sum.start_date BETWEEN d.start_date AND d.end_date) tot_days
    FROM
        dates d
)
SELECT
    start_date, MAX(end_date) end_date
FROM
    sum_days
WHERE
    tot_days = 5
GROUP BY
    start_date
```

It works, but it is inefficient. The real table that I'm using has 1,000 rows, and it takes over 1 minute for the query to return.

My question: is there a better way?

Input:

| start_date | working_days |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-09 | 1 |
| 2023-01-10 | 1 |
| 2023-01-11 | 1 |
| 2023-01-12 | 1 |
| 2023-01-13 | 1 |
| 2023-01-14 | 0 |
| 2023-01-15 | 0 |
| 2023-01-16 | 0 |
| 2023-01-17 | 1 |
| 2023-01-18 | 1 |
| 2023-01-19 | 1 |
| 2023-01-20 | 1 |
| 2023-01-21 | 0 |
| 2023-01-22 | 0 |
| 2023-01-23 | 1 |
| 2023-01-24 | 1 |

Desired output:

| start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-09 | 2023-01-16 |
| 2023-01-10 | 2023-01-17 |
| 2023-01-11 | 2023-01-18 |
| 2023-01-12 | 2023-01-19 |
| 2023-01-13 | 2023-01-22 |
| 2023-01-14 | 2023-01-23 |
| 2023-01-15 | 2023-01-23 |
| 2023-01-16 | 2023-01-23 |
| 2023-01-17 | 2023-01-23 |
| 2023-01-18 | 2023-01-24 |

SQL to create the table:

```
drop table if exists #t;
GO

select '2023-01-09' start_date,1 working_days into #t;
GO

insert into #t values('2023-01-10',1) ;
go 

insert into #t values('2023-01-11',1);
insert into #t values('2023-01-12',1);
insert into #t values('2023-01-13',1);
insert into #t values('2023-01-14',0);
insert into #t values('2023-01-15',0);
insert into #t values('2023-01-16',0);
insert into #t values('2023-01-17',1);
insert into #t values('2023-01-18',1);
insert into #t values('2023-01-19',1);
insert into #t values('2023-01-20',1);
insert into #t values('2023-01-21',0);
insert into #t values('2023-01-22',0);
insert into #t values('2023-01-23',1);
insert into #t values('2023-01-24',1);
go
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Its because of the quadratic complexity of the triangular join. If you need a running total there are much better ways. With 1,000 rows in `#t`. dates will have 499500 (`N*(N-1)/2`)

Comment: @Martin Smith, yes, I'm sure there are better ways.  I just don't know how to build a SQL for this, hence my question.

Comment: Can you check your posted "Desired Output" data? The last two rows seem to select four workdays ahead instead of five, and one row selects a non-workday 2023-01-22.

Comment: @TN - It seems to be that if current day is a work day then include it and count next 4 working days ahead. If current day is not a work day then count next 5 working days ahead. If this takes you up to just before a section of non working days then include all those. `2023-01-16` in the very first desired result row is also a non working day (at end of three consecutive non working days)

Comment: Okay. I still don't understand the 2023-01-09 -> 2023-01-16 case, but the answer does matches the OP's desired output.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Do you actually want 18th and 24th to match up? That's not five day ahead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
FROM #t t_from, #t t_to
where t_from.start_date < t_to.start_date
```

is a "triangular" join. It is not quite as bad as a cross join but getting that way (rows returned are `N*(N-1)/2` rather than `N*N`).

This will not scale with large numbers of rows in `#t`.

One way of getting your desired results ([db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9rZWpre0)) is

```
WITH Dates
     AS (SELECT *,
                sum(working_days)
                  OVER (
                    ORDER BY start_date) AS working_day_count
         FROM   #t)
SELECT D1.start_date,
       MAX(D2.start_date)
FROM   Dates D1
       JOIN Dates D2
         ON D1.working_day_count + 5 - D1.working_days = D2.working_day_count
GROUP  BY D1.start_date
```

This calculates the running total efficiently. Potentially a solution will be provided that does it all in one pass rather than requiring the self join above but this is at least an equi join and should be a lot faster in your 1,000 row case than your current method.

Comment: If by chance `working_days` is a `bit` type, `sum(working_days)` can be changed to `sum(cast(working_days as int))`.

Comment: Or `sum(0+working_days)`

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, look at the solution without JOIN

```
with cte as (
select start_date,working_days
  ,lead(start_date,1)over(order by start_date ) d1
  ,lead(start_date,4)over(order by start_date ) d2 -- target date
  ,lead(start_date,5)over(order by start_date ) d3 --target+1, if not_working_days between d2 and d3
from (select * from #t where working_days=1) t -- dates, only working_days
)
,t2 as(
select * 
 ,case when datediff(d,d2,d3)>1 then dateadd(d,-1,d3)
       else d2
  end end_date
 ,datediff(d,start_date,d1) dn
from cte
)
select  
    dateadd(d,isnull(n,0),start_date) start_date
   ,case when isnull(n,0)=0 then working_days else 0 end working_days
   ,case when isnull(n,0)=0 then end_date else dateadd(d,1,end_date) end end_date
from t2 left join (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5))nn(n) --to restore not_working_days
      on nn.n<t2.dn
```

If there is an opportunity to compare the cost, it will be interesting.
[Test example](https://dbfiddle.uk/mmytya3x)

Answer (score 0):

```
with data as (
    select start_date as dt, working_days as adj,
        sum(cast(working_days as int)) over (order by start_date) as ofs
    from #t
)
select ds.dt as start_date, de.dt as end_date
from data ds cross apply (
    select max(dt) as end_date
    from data de
    where de.ofs = ds.ofs + 5 - ds.adj
) de(dt)
where de.dt is not null;
```

Basically the same as above but cross apply might be improvement. This seems to favor a clustered index on `start_date` in my experiments.

Or you could just search via `lead()`:

```
with data as (
    select start_date as dt, working_days as adj,
        sum(cast(working_days as int)) over (order by start_date) as ofs
    from #t
), data2 as (
    select dt as start_date,
        case ofs + 5 - adj -- check in reverse order
            when lead(ofs, 9) over (order by dt) then lead(dt, 9) over (order by dt)
            when lead(ofs, 8) over (order by dt) then lead(dt, 8) over (order by dt)
            when lead(ofs, 7) over (order by dt) then lead(dt, 7) over (order by dt)
            when lead(ofs, 6) over (order by dt) then lead(dt, 6) over (order by dt) 
        end as end_date
    from data
)
select * from data2 where end_date is not null;
```

This query assumes at least two days off per week and a maximum of four-day weekends to limit the number of dates that need to be searched. Expand as necessary.

Check out the fiddle here with a demonstration that both of these approaches seem to generate cheaper plans: https://dbfiddle.uk/1SdBRmmg

There is a way to use a single pass over the data. You'll have to wrap it up in a table expression to filter the null values near the end of the calendar.

```
select start_date,
    dateadd(day,
        case 5
            when sum(working_days) over (order by start_date rows between current row and 9 following) then 9
            when sum(working_days) over (order by start_date rows between current row and 8 following) then 8
            when sum(working_days) over (order by start_date rows between current row and 7 following) then 7
            when sum(working_days) over (order by start_date rows between current row and 6 following) then 6
        end,
        start_date) as end_date
from #t;
```

And just for fun you could do this with `range over` (https://dbfiddle.uk/cm3KJO-W) just not on SQL Server yet:

```
with data as (select *, sum(working_days) over (order by start_date) as ofs from t)
select start_date,
    max(start_date) over (order by ofs range between 5 following and 5 following) as end_date
from data;
```

Comment: Great ideas and impressive technique.  We have situations (e.g. at the end of the year) where we have extended shutdowns so I can't make an assumption about the number of rows between endpoints.

Comment: @mherzog You can always extend the logic as far as necessary as long as you can figure at least figure out what the maximum gap is going to be.